# Oracle developer suit 10g setup crashes during installation

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am new to database, i want to install oracle developer 10g on Windows 10 64bit.

But the setup crashes when I run installer.

Here is a snap,

[image]

Please help

Comment: What exactly are you trying to install, and where, and where did you get it from? Is it certified on your platform? Have you looked for a log file to see what happened? You”ve tagged this as SQL Developer, so do you really [only need that](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html)?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like Windows 10.

Try to run setup in Windows XP SP3 compatibility mode.

Comment: Ah! The Windows 10 image was more attractive than "5.1".